# Enabling CORS for a SOAP-webservice in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, stenciljs

I've a Spring-boot soap webservice running. Whenever I post a request with postman it works with the header `text/xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:gs="http://testschema.com/hr/schemas">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <gs:startProcess>
            <gs:root>
                <gs:metadata>
                    <gs:signature>officia eu Lo</gs:signature>
                    <gs:source>qui adipisicing esse</gs:source>
                </gs:metadata>
                <gs:xmlMessage>enim et</gs:xmlMessage>
            </gs:root>
        </gs:startProcess>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now i've made an StencilJS component which uses the Fetch-API to send the same request. (request extracted from postman). Whenever I execute this request it returns the following CORS-error:

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

In my spring-boot app i've a class annotated with `@Endpoint` and a method that looks like the following

```
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "startProcess")
    @ResponsePayload
    public EndResult startProcess(@RequestPayload StartProcess request)  {
```

And my StencilJS is the following:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    
    var raw = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\r\n                xmlns:gs=\"http://testschema.com/hr/schemas\">\r\n   <soapenv:Header/>\r\n   <soapenv:Body>\r\n      <gs:startProcess>\r\n        <gs:root>\r\n         <gs:metadata>\r\n            <gs:signature>officia eu Lo</gs:signature>\r\n            <gs:source>qui adipisicing esse</gs:source>\r\n         </gs:metadata>\r\n         <gs:xmlMessage>enim et</gs:xmlMessage>\r\n        </gs:root>\r\n      </gs:startProcess>\r\n   </soapenv:Body>\r\n</soapenv:Envelope>";

    
    fetch("http://localhost:8090/ws", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
```

How would I enable CORS in this spring-boot soap webservice?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-cors-configuration/), it is a useful overview of Spring CORS handling.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create 1 class config to configure cors as follows, it will solve your problem.

```
  @Configuration
public class SoapWebServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
        return loggingFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilterRegistration() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }}
```